# top -H option in Macosx

Tags: linux, macos, top-command

In Unix/Linux the top command has the -H option to give a more details information about the threads within a process.
On Macosx there seems to be no -H option! Is there anything similar for Macosx?

Answer (score 4):

I think there's no such or similar option in top for OS X, but you can try htop which displays threads in somewhat similar way to htop -H.

Although OS X doesn't have htop binary, you can build and install it from source (e. g. according to this guide: https://web.archive.org/web/20110122020519/http://geektechnica.com/2009/07/how-to-install-htop-on-osx )

Comment: @Vigneshwaran thanks, I've replaced it with a version from internet archive :)