# How to find the thread id through the process in macOS ？

Tags: macos

such as in Linux: `top -Hp [pid]`, but it is invalid on macOS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [top -H option in Macosx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5461010/top-h-option-in-macosx)

Comment: Why is this tagged with java?

Answer (score 2):

you can use `ps -M` command to show all thread of each process, whith have the some PID. but it does not show the threadid.